# How to convert a blob into word document in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I tried code but it's downloading a corrupt file in word document and file name is coming as undefined. Not getting the original file name

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, `${name}.docx`);
 } else {
  const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(a);
  a.href = url;
  a.download = `${name}.docx`;
  a.click();
  
 }
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far (your code).

Answer (score 1):

Try this approach:

```
if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
  window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob, `${name}.docx`);
 } else {
  const blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  link.download = `${name}.docx`;
  link.click();
 }
}
```

Comment: Getting error downloading the file after adding this code

Comment: Can you share the error here? @AnjonRoy